# Electron AutoUpdate does not apply after restart. OSX

Tags: reactjs, electron, auto-update, electron-forge

My Code

https://github.com/mergeweb/electron-forge-updater-v6

I have an updater in place but when the app quits and restarts, the update is not applied.

1. How can I debug this?
2. Do you know where the updated file is downloaded?
3. Does the update file have to be a dmg?

   1. (Update) - [Looks like the file does not have to be dmg.](https://github.com/electron/update-electron-app/blob/master/readme.md#what-kinds-of-assets-do-i-need-to-build)

[image]

```
    const dialogOpts = {
        type: 'info',
        buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
        title: 'Application Update',
        message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
        detail:
            'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.'
    };

    dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts, response => {
        if (response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
    });
```